# Nested Dialog Procedures

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog, gdi

I'm not sure how to call Dialog Procedures of certain classes and was looking for some help.

I'm aware for a normal Message Procedure you can do this in the MessageProc:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{   
    CREATESTRUCT* cs = (CREATESTRUCT*)_lParam;
    pApplication = (CApplication*)cs->lpCreateParams;

    return pApplication->MessageProc(_Msg, _wParam, _lParam);
}
```

which will allow you to create a Message Proc independent to the class.

However due to the fact I don't know exactly how the first two lines work (just the definition that they return the 'this' pointer of the application), I can't work out what to do to get my Dialog Procedures to do a similar thing

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
{
    //How can I get the pointer to the inspector that 
    //I want to call the dialog proc on?

    return pInspector->DlgProc(_hWndDlg, _Msg, _wParam, _lParam);
}
```

Any help to both get the pointer to the inspector working and also clarify exactly what the other two lines are doing in WM_CREATE would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a window is created, it receives a `WM_CREATE` message with a pointer to a `CREATESTRUCT` structure, and in there is a pointer-sized userdata field (`lpCreateParams`). This value comes from the `lpParam` argument passed to the `CreateWindowEx()` function.

This is the general mechanism which lets you associate your own class or data structure with an instance of a window.

This pointer generally needs to be saved somewhere in order to use it later on. One common way of doing this is to store it in a window property:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    CREATESTRUCT* cs = (CREATESTRUCT*)_lParam;
    pApplication = (CApplication*)cs->lpCreateParams;

    SetProp(hWnd, L"my.property", (HANDLE)pApplication);
}
```

Then to retrieve the value when handling other messages:

```
pApplication = (CApplication*)GetProp(hWnd, L"my.property");
```

Dialogs are not exactly like normal windows, so although a similar mechanism exists, it is implemented differently. When a dialog procedure receives the `WM_INITDIALOG` message, the `lParam` value is equivalent to the `lpCreateParams` value in a `WM_CREATE` message.

In order to save your `pInspector` value it would need to have been provided as the `dwInitParam` value when the dialog was created, but assuming that it was, you can handle this in a similar way:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
{
    pInspector = (CInspector*)lParam;
    SetProp(hWnd, L"my.property", (HANDLE)pInspector);
}
```

And to retrieve the value when handling other messages:

```
pInspector = (CInspector*)GetProp(hWnd, L"my.property");
```

Comment: Thank you, so clear and concise, and the extra info about saving the properties will also be extremely helpful as the project gets more complex. Cheers